# Lucas Sequence in Java

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to display x amount of numbers in Lucas Sequence using my method that I am using, I am using while and else if. I'm using that because I'm new to programming and I'm just learning. I have tried to make the code look like this but when I try to do it, it just doesn't work.

The code type I use is :

```
           int add4 = 1;
           int count500 = 1;
           while (count500 <= 500)

            {
              if (count500 ==1)
                {
                  System.out.print(add4);
                }
          else
                {
                  System.out.print (add4 +"," +"");
                }
                  add4 =add4 + 4; 
                  count500 ++;            
            }
```

This is just the method I'm trying to do it in but it doesn't work out and it just gets over my head atm.

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Does it not compile? If so, what is the error and on what line? Does it not give expected output? If so, what is the expectation and actual output?

Comment: 1,5,9,13,17... Yes, this is not a Lucas Sequence. It's a linear sequence `a_n=4n+1`. I think the problem is that you implemented the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/fibonacci-and-lucas-sequences.html

It's a page that contains the explanation of lucas sequence and have an implementation.

And here there is a complete explanation of lucas sequence.

http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/lucasNbs.html

Answer (score 0):

The definition you have for the Lucas number is recursive, i.e., to calculate the Nth lucas number, you already need to know the N-1th and the N-2nd.

```
public int lucas(int N) {
if( N == 0 ) return 2;
if( N == 1 ) return 1;
return lucas(N-1) + lucas(N-2);
```

}
However, you only have to print the numbers, don't you? Then it's quite easy, actually.

```
int L2 = 2;
int L1 = 1;
for( int i = 2; i <= N; i++ ) {
int L = L1 + L2;
print(L); //or whatever output function you have
L2 = L1;
L1 = L;
}
```

The idea is to keep the last two numbers, which you need to compute the next two numbers, always at hand.

PS: These Lucas numbers are just like the Fibonacci numbers with different starting values, so any algorithm for the Fibonacci numbers will do. If you're really good at math, you can even try to find a closed formula for the Lucas numbers, but it's definitely beyond high school math (search tag would be "linear difference equation with constant coefficients").